# How to solve Oscommerce, Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, oscommerce

I install the latest version of OSCommerce framework. in backend Categories/Products error shown like:

> Warning: sizeof(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in C:\xampp\htdocs\oscommerce\catalog\admin\includes\functions\general.php on line 93

I try to use `is_array()` and `count()` but still not working, below are the code

```
    function tep_get_path($current_category_id = '') {
    global $cPath_array;

    if ($current_category_id == '') {
      $cPath_new = implode('_', $cPath_array);
    } else {
      if (sizeof($cPath_array) == 0) {
        $cPath_new = $current_category_id;
      } else {
        $cPath_new = '';
        $last_category_query = tep_db_query("select parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " where 
        categories_id = '" . (int)$cPath_array[(sizeof($cPath_array)-1)] . "'");
        $last_category = tep_db_fetch_array($last_category_query);

        $current_category_query = tep_db_query("select parent_id from " . TABLE_CATEGORIES . " where 
        categories_id = '" . (int)$current_category_id . "'");
        $current_category = tep_db_fetch_array($current_category_query);

        if ($last_category['parent_id'] == $current_category['parent_id']) {
          for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($cPath_array) - 1; $i < $n; $i++) {
            $cPath_new .= '_' . $cPath_array[$i];
          }
        } else {
          for ($i = 0, $n = sizeof($cPath_array); $i < $n; $i++) {
            $cPath_new .= '_' . $cPath_array[$i];
          }
        }

        $cPath_new .= '_' . $current_category_id;

        if (substr($cPath_new, 0, 1) == '_') {
          $cPath_new = substr($cPath_new, 1);
        }
      }
    }

    return 'cPath=' . $cPath_new;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

I added below code in the file just the line which was giving  the error.

```
if ($cPath_array == null) {
    $cPath_array = array();
}
```

It has resolved my error

Answer (score 1):

[sizeof](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof.php) is an alias of [count](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php).

`count`'s behavior changed in Php 7.2.

> count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.

**Possible causes:**

```
var_dump(count([])); // OK
var_dump(count((object)[])); // Warning
var_dump(count(null)); // Warning
var_dump(count(false)); // Warning
var_dump(count(123)); // Warning
var_dump(count('123')); // Warning
```

Please check the data type of `$cPath_array` using [var_dump](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php). `$cPath_array` is implemented as array in the code but whats its actual value for which warning is generated.

**Bad and Temporary solution:**
Downgrade your Php version.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use [`empty()`](https://php.net/empty). It checks if a variable is "[falsy](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting)".

```
if (empty($cPath_array)) { }
```

Instead of

```
if (sizeof($cPath_array) == 0) { }
```